# EC2 セキュリティグループで OutBounds を閉じても DNS が引けてしまう謎

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, vpc

EC2インスタンスをたててセキュリティグループのOutBoundsをTCP(22,80,443)のみに設定してるにも関わらず
nslookup をひくとサブネット内と通信をして名前がひけてしまいます

DNS は開けようと思ってたのでそれはそれでいいのですが
逆にあいてると思ってないところがあいてたりすると怖いので理由が知りたいです

EC2は特別な設定はなく
構築はAWSコンソールから t2.micro, t3.micro で一番上の Linux イメージから作成
VPC上の適当なサブネット上に配置
他の設定もほぼデフォルトで作成した後セキュリティグループのみ変更しました
別のVPCで２度ためしたんですがどちらも再現します

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VPCのサブネットではDNSサーバーが提供](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#vpc-sizing-ipv4)されています。そのため、サブネットから外に出ることなく名前解決が可能です。

> たとえば、CIDR ブロック 10.0.0.0/24 を持つサブネットの場合、次の 5 つの IP アドレスが予約されます。
>
> - ...
> - 10.0.0.2: AWS で予約されています。DNS サーバーの IP アドレスは、常に VPC ネットワークのベースに 2 を付加したものですが、各サブネット範囲のベースに 2 を付加したアドレスも予約されています。